# Having trouble with MAIN please advise

Tags: java

Sorry guys I am new to Java and I have an issue with my code. I have read through the threads and have seen many examples regarding this specific error `(java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main")`. I just cant seem to wrap my head around where I would add (`static void main(String[] args)`) to the code. If you guys can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Here is what I have:

```
public class Employee {


String name;
String department;

double hourlyRate;

Employee(String name, String department, double hourlyRate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.department = department;
    this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
}

public void setDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyRate) {
    this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
}

public String getNameAndDepartment() {
    return name + " " + department;
}

double weeklyPay(int numOfHourWorked) {
    if (numOfHourWorked < 40) {
        return (numOfHourWorked * hourlyRate);
    } else
        return (40 * hourlyRate);

}
}

class UnionEmployee extends Employee {

double dues;

UnionEmployee(String name, String department, double hourlyRate, double dues) {
    super(name, department, hourlyRate);
    this.dues = dues;
}

public void setDues(double dues) {
    this.dues = dues;
}

double weeklyPay(int numOfHourWorked) {
    if (numOfHourWorked <= 40) {
        return (super.weeklyPay(numOfHourWorked));
    } else
return ((super.weeklyPay(40) + ((numOfHourWorked - 40) * hourlyRate * 1.5)) - dues);
}
}

class CommissionEmployee extends Employee {

double commisionRate;
double salesAmount;

CommissionEmployee(String name, String department, double hourlyRate) {
    super(name, department, hourlyRate);
}

public void setCommisionRate(double commisionRate) {
    this.commisionRate = commisionRate;
}

public void setSalesAmount(double salesAmount) {
    this.salesAmount = salesAmount;
}

double weeklyPay(int numOfHourWorked) {
    return (super.weeklyPay(numOfHourWorked) + (commisionRate * salesAmount));
}

}

class TestEmployee {
UnionEmployee uEmp = new UnionEmployee(null, null, 0, 0);
CommissionEmployee cEmp = new CommissionEmployee(null, null, 0);
Employee emp = new Employee(null, null, 0);

void display(Employee emp, int numOfHourWorked) {
    System.out.println("Name and department :" + emp.getNameAndDepartment    ());
    System.out.println("Weekly pay of employee :"
            + emp.weeklyPay(numOfHourWorked));
}

void display(UnionEmployee uEmp, CommissionEmployee cEmp,
        int numOfHourWorked) {
    System.out.println("Weekly Pay for UnionEmployee"
            + uEmp.weeklyPay(numOfHourWorked));
    System.out.println("Weekly Pay for UnionEmployee"
            + cEmp.weeklyPay(numOfHourWorked));
}

}
```

OK so I started by separating each class into a different file. In looking through the Java tutorials it said to add static void main(String[] args) the way the tutorial had it setup was like this:

```
public class Misc {
static void main(String[] args) {

//body
   }
}
```

So I did this:

```
class TestEmployee {

static void main(String[] args) {

UnionEmployee uEmp = new UnionEmployee(null, null, 0, 0);
CommissionEmployee cEmp = new CommissionEmployee(null, null, 0);
Employee emp = new Employee(null, null, 0);

void display(Employee emp, int numOfHourWorked) {
    System.out.println("Name and department :" + emp.getNameAndDepartment    ());
    System.out.println("Weekly pay of employee :"
            + emp.weeklyPay(numOfHourWorked));
}

void display(UnionEmployee uEmp, CommissionEmployee cEmp,
        int numOfHourWorked) {
    System.out.println("Weekly Pay for UnionEmployee"
            + uEmp.weeklyPay(numOfHourWorked));
    System.out.println("Weekly Pay for UnionEmployee"
            + cEmp.weeklyPay(numOfHourWorked));
}

}

}
```

Still get the same error : (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main").

OK I add public but now I get this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

```
void is an invalid type for the variable display
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Duplicate local variable emp
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
void is an invalid type for the variable display
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Duplicate local variable uEmp
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Duplicate local variable cEmp
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
Duplicate local variable numOfHourWorked
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

at TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:9)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem with main is that it doesn't exist, and you need to put one in your program for it to run. Put it in the main class, whichever one that is, but while it needs to be *inside* of the class, inside of the curly braces that define the class, you must also make sure that you don't put it inside of another method.

Above, I'd put it in TestEmployee.

I'd also take care to make sure every class above is declared public and is in its *own* file. So your code above which contains 4 classes, should be comprised of 4 files.

---

**Edit**
Also, be sure to declare your main method as a *public* method as @Aniket noted in comment below.

---

**Edit 2**

- You're still not declaring main as a *public* method.
- You have methods embedded within the main method. Remember that in Java you can't do this since all methods need to be class level. Get them out of the main method.
- Your code indentation is horrible to say the least, and this will make it *very* difficult for you or us to see your coding problems. You will want to invest time and effort towards indenting your code properly. If you did this, you would see in an instant that you had methods inside of methods.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. Is there something I can reference to see how this is done so I can do it right?

Comment: @user2975434: you bet! First check the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), and in particular [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html).

Comment: I must be really dumb or I am missing something. I tried adding it in TestEmployee with no luck. Does anyone know of any other tutorials I could go through to try to find a solution to my problem?

Comment: @user2975434: more tutorials likely won't help. What you should do is edit your original question. At the bottom of your question, please attach your latest code showing where you put the main method, discussing any other changes to your code, showing any and all error messages, and describing fully all misbehaviors. Also, are you putting all of your Java classes in separate files?

Comment: shouldn't main be `public` too?

Comment: @Aniket: indeed it should!

Comment: @user2975434: please see edit to answer regarding Aniket's comment above.

Comment: Thank you Aniket for your response. I added the list of errors I get now.

Comment: @user2975434: see **Edit 2** to answr.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty and your guidance I will continue to look for a solution to my problem. I appreciate your time.